# Open source project that uses cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Can anyone let me know about any open source c/c++ project that uses cmake to build its code base?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [success stories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/project/success.html) page of CMake project.
The most notable projects (IMO of course) are **KDE** and **MySQL**.

Answer (score 1):

[opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) uses cmake

Answer (score 1):

[Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake#Notable_applications) open source projects use CMake. Two examples that I use are: the
[Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) render engine
and
[CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), a 3D GUI framework.

Comment: i just quote two projects i am using.

Comment: OK - I suspect you're thinking of 'Two of the many open source projects that use CMake are: Ogre3D ... and CEGUI ...'?  Would that be fair?  Your wording 'Too many' means that there are a lot of projects that use CMake but (implicitly) they should not be doing so.

Comment: sorry for missing Wikipedia link, and i must apologize for my English

Answer (score 0):

Out of the top of my mind comes [compiz](http://www.compiz.org).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake#Notable_applications) has a rather long list of these as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just started to use cmake. It's quite practical and much easier to use than the usual Unix approach (configure script generated with the auto-tools suite.)

There is an example, if you wanted to use Cassandra (used by Facebook, Twitter, Google):

http://sf.net/p/libqtcassandra